# Issues with CPU speed after some time

Tags: cpu, temperature

I've been runing a model called WRF on my laptop, using Ubuntu 16.04. For running that model I use four of the eight cpu cores. Normally the model runs at a rate of 0.05 seconds per time step, and when it is running CPU temperature raises to 85-92°C. I normally use my laptop for runing other kind of programs while the model is running, I haven't had any problem with that.

The last week I realized that the laptop performance slows down dramatically while the model is running, I mean, the model starts running the same as always, but at some time the time per time step increases almost 100 times, and the CPU temperature decreases to 55-60°C. It's similar to what happend when the battery is almost drained off.

It only is fixed when I reboot the laptop, but I want to have some idea of what's going on. It fixes too for a few minutes when I unplug the charger (the laptop it's always charged), but then It stays the same.

Do you have any idea what's going on?

Comment: Yes, you are likely hitting thermal throttling, limiting CPU frequencies to reduce energy consumption, thereby reducing waste heat. Investigation methods depends on your processor. What is the make and model of your processor?

Comment: it's possible the heat and wear and tear of time has gradually been chipping away at the quality of the contact provided by the thermal paste (and also where it resides may have slipped) between your cpu and your radiator. Therefore the cpu has to fight the new heat by an increased ammount micropauses which affects the speed for resolving tasks negatively.

Comment: @DougSmythies My processor is intel core i7 6700hq. I've been thinking that it's a temperature issue too, but according to cpu manufacturer critical temperature is 100°C, and it has never arised over 95°C. Thank you for comment

Comment: By default, you should be running the intel_pstate CPU frequency scaling driver. Check via `grep . /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy?/scaling_driver`. so you should be able to test limiting the highest CPU frequnecy via `echo 80 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/intel_pstate/max_perf_pct`. Just for a test try it, reducing the max % until it doesn't hit the thermal trigger. Note, typically the trip point is below the critical temperature. Search the logs (say `/var/log/kern.log`)for temperature related messages.